# C Memory Management -> Hash

Tags: c, algorithm, hash, hashtable

I don't know if my problem is a memory leak, or i'm not acessing the hashtable in the correct way.

My hash.h

```
#define HASHSIZE 31
#define EMPTY   ""
#define DELETED "-"

typedef char KeyType[9];

typedef void *Info;

typedef struct entry
{
    KeyType key;
    Info info;
}Entry;

typedef Entry HashTable[HASHSIZE];
```

My hash.c

```
int Hash(KeyType k){
    return atoi(k)%HASHSIZE;
}

void InitializeTable(HashTable t){
    for(int i=0; i < HASHSIZE; i++){
        strncpy(t[i].key,EMPTY,9);
    }
}

void ClearTable(HashTable t){
    InitializeTable(t);
}

void InsertTable_LP(HashTable t, KeyType k, Info i){
    int a = 0;
    int hash = Hash(k);
    while((a<HASHSIZE) 
            && strcmp(t[hash].key,EMPTY)!=0
                && strcmp(t[hash].key,DELETED)!=0  ){
        hash = (hash + 1) % HASHSIZE;
        a++;
    }

    strncpy(t[hash].key,k,9);
    t[hash].info = i;
    printf("Value of info is %d\n",(int)t[hash].info);

}

int RetrieveTable_LP(HashTable t, KeyType k){
    int a=0;
    int hash = Hash(k);

    while(a<HASHSIZE 
            && strcmp(t[hash].key,k)!=0
                && strcmp(t[hash].key,EMPTY)!=0){
        hash=(hash+1) % HASHSIZE;
        a++;    
    }

    if(strcmp(t[hash].key,k)==0)
        return hash;
    return -1;

}


int main(){
    HashTable *t = malloc(HASHSIZE*sizeof(Entry));
    int valores[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};

    ClearTable(*t);
    InsertTable_LP(*t,"1",valores);
    InsertTable_LP(*t,"2",valores+1);
    InsertTable_LP(*t,"3",valores+2);
    InsertTable_LP(*t,"4",valores+3);
    InsertTable_LP(*t,"5",valores+4);

    int pos = RetrieveTable_LP(*t,"2");
    if(pos==-1){
        printf("Error\n");
    }
    else
        printf("Position %d\n",pos);
        printf("okay %d\n",(int)t[pos]->info);

    printf("asdasdas\n");

    return 1;
}
```

My output is

```
Value of info is 1537727040
Value of info is 1537727044
Value of info is 1537727048
Value of info is 1537727052
Value of info is 1537727056
Position 2
okay 0
```

If anyone could explain me, thanks in advance.

Comment: just a first look to your code and i can see that `(int)t[hash].info` is totally wrong: you are casting `Info` which is `void*` to `int`

Comment: Get this as an exercise, not as my own implementation. Even so, if i'm not wrong void* let me get the any kind of variable, since i entered an int for info, i can cast it out as int.

Comment: you mean **dereferencing** it ! it is not obvious it would be `*(int*)` instead of `(int)` though !! Good Luck anyway !

Comment: Thanks @Meninx! But if i do that, i get a segmentation fault, but as @iharob said, the problem can be at the insert function ! That's why before came in here, i tried out the printf inside the function before came in here.

Comment: hope you solved your problem  ! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `malloc` is not necessary the reason why that wasn't obvious is because it was hidden by the way you `typedef`d the `HashTable`, don't ever do that, the following code works as you expected yours to do

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define HASHSIZE 31
#define EMPTY   ""
#define DELETED "-"

typedef char KeyType[9];

typedef void *Info;

typedef struct entry
{
    KeyType key;
    Info info;
}Entry;

typedef Entry HashTable[HASHSIZE];

int Hash(KeyType k){
    return atoi(k)%HASHSIZE;
}

void InitializeTable(HashTable t) {
    int i;
    for(i=0; i < HASHSIZE; i++) {
        strncpy(t[i].key, EMPTY, 9);
    }
}

void ClearTable(HashTable t) {
    InitializeTable(t);
}

void InsertTable_LP(HashTable t, KeyType k, Info i){
    int a = 0;
    int hash = Hash(k);
    while((a<HASHSIZE) && strcmp(t[hash].key, EMPTY) !=0 && strcmp(t[hash].key, DELETED) !=0  ) {
        hash = (hash + 1) % HASHSIZE;
        a++;
    }
    strncpy(t[hash].key, k, 9);

    t[hash].info = i;

    printf("Value of info is %p\n", t[hash].info);

}

int RetrieveTable_LP(HashTable t, KeyType k){
    int a=0;
    int hash = Hash(k);

    while(a<HASHSIZE 
            && strcmp(t[hash].key,k)!=0
                && strcmp(t[hash].key,EMPTY)!=0){
        hash=(hash+1) % HASHSIZE;
        a++;    
    }

    printf("%s, %s\n", t[hash].key, k);
    if(strcmp(t[hash].key, k)==0)
        return hash;
    return -1;

}


int main(){
    /* 
     * You don't need to malloc, since HashTable is an array,
     * and it does not need to be a pointer, since it decays
     * to one when passed as such.
     */
    HashTable t;// = malloc(HASHSIZE * sizeof(Entry));
    int valores[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};

    ClearTable(t);

    InsertTable_LP(t,"1",valores);
    InsertTable_LP(t,"2",valores+1);
    InsertTable_LP(t,"3",valores+2);
    InsertTable_LP(t,"4",valores+3);
    InsertTable_LP(t,"5",valores+4);

    int pos = RetrieveTable_LP(t, "2");
    if(pos==-1) {
        printf("Error\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Position %d\n",pos);
        printf("okay %p\n", t[pos].info);
    }

    printf("asdasdas\n");

    return 1;
}
```

your `typedef` of the `HashTable` makes it hard to know what to do with a `HashTable` type variable, that is not a very good use of `typedef`.

Also the second `printf` will be executed regardless of the condition

```
else
    printf("Position %d\n",pos);
    printf("okay %d\n",(int)t[pos]->info);
```

you need to add `{`

```
else
{
    printf("Position %d\n",pos);
    printf("okay %d\n",(int)t[pos]->info);
}
```

Comment: Sorry i wasn't very explicit, I know i was printing memory positions. But my problem was the printf in else, that i get zero as the value of the elemento at position 2.
Tried the same correction, but that way i get a segmentation fault.

Comment: @Duozhasht You should use `unsigned` for that to work properly. Or use the `"%p"` specifier.

Comment: Once again, you're right, but before i printed the position i was just printing the Okay + valueofinfo. Even so i keep getting zero. Like i lost the value at that memory position.
(Offtopic)
As you see, i have hard trouble dealing with memory in C, pherhaps if you could point me in the right direction, or recommend a good book.

Comment: Yes in fact the problem appears to be in your `RetrieveTable_LP` function, hang on I almost found it.

Comment: Oh man, you're like a second god, first is an older teacher of mine. You guys must eat bits and bytes at breakfast! Really ty !
And in order not to open another question, i should only malloc if i want space for a memory position ?

Answer (score 1):

`valores` is an array.  You are inserting `Info` which has been `typedef`ed to `void *`.  You need to fix those things.

Comment: This should be a comment instead of an answer.

Comment: Even so, the header file it's from an exercise, if i could change it my structure for HashTable would be a pointer, and it was easier for me to work with that.